# matplotlib plot line/bar using two x values from excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have this kind of data from my excel sheet:

[image]

Let's say I already import and read the data,

the question is how to make this kind of plot using matplotlib? where the y values contains two inputs to plot (top and base from excel above). Sorry I am so clueless on this thing, please help. Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `plt.bar` as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Top': [78, 159, 265, 277], 'Bottom': [85, 212, 272, 278]})

plt.bar(x=[0] * len(df), height=df['Bottom'] - df['Top'], bottom=df['Top'], fc='turquoise', ec='black')
plt.xticks([])
plt.xlim(-0.5, 5)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]